# How to emulate a Bluetooth remote controller on my Surface Pro 9 for accessibility?

Tags: windows, winapi, bluetooth, emulation

I am looking for a way to emulate a Bluetooth remote controller on my Surface Pro 9.

**For context:** I have a lift that assists me in getting up stairs, and it's operated via a Bluetooth remote controller. Due to physical impairments, I'm unable to use my hands, which makes operating the standard remote controller impossible. I am exploring ways to control the lift using my Surface Pro 9, leveraging its Bluetooth capabilities.

Is there any software or method that would allow me to pair my Surface Pro 9 with the lift's Bluetooth system and emulate the remote controller's functions?

Comment: Depends on your RC Bluetooth protocol. There are at least 2 (except any custom): standard HID and BLE. If it is HID then there is no easy way to do what you need. If it is BLE then it can be possible. If it is any custom: need to know does it use L2CAP or RFCOMM to send commands.

Comment: If you can provide any additional details about your devices (at least model) I can try to find some info about possability of what you need.